# Eclipse Maven: Unknown errors in pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I recently imported a bunch of Maven projects(Ardor3D if it helps) into Eclipse, and for some reason, in all but the first project, there is a little red x mark next to the pom.xml file in the Package Explorer window indicating there is an error, however when I open the pom.xml, I can't find any error...thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you looked in Problems view?

Comment: Invalidate casches in your IDE and reimport project then rebuild it.

Comment: right click on that error and do quick fix, probably some eclipse conf issue

Comment: Just looked and it says "Description Resource Path Location Type
Cannot read lifecycle mapping metadata for artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:maven-plugin:2.8.1:runtime Cause: error in opening zip file pom.xml /ardor3d-animation line 1 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting Unknown error in line 1 of pom.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56142369/why-am-i-getting-unknown-error-in-line-1-of-pom-xml)

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:

[Why am I getting Unknown error in line 1 of pom.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56142369/why-am-i-getting-unknown-error-in-line-1-of-pom-xml)

---

For me, after I hit this problem, I upgrade my STS from 4.0 to 4.7.1 and problem goes away, like someone also mentioned in that link.