# Why am I getting Unknown error in line 1 of pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

Getting unknown error at Line 1 in `pom.xml` in Eclipse IDE.
It was working fine till yesterday, but all of a sudden after updating my project from master and after fixing merge conflicts getting "Unknown error" in pom.xml.
Except me, none of my teammates are facing this issue. I also changed the workspace, deleted cache but still no luck.

I am using the h2 database for this project, in spite of inserting values in data.sql, it is not picking up any values and inserting into h2 DB tables. Before this issue, it was working fine. I feel its due to the issue in pom.xml, I am not sure though. Please help

I deleted the existing project and took the latest code from master. After that deleted .m2 folder under users including the repository folder.  I did update project and enabled Forced update of snapshots/releases, maven clean and maven build. But nothing helps.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.abc.roster</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-roster-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>spring-boot-roster-app</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot Roster</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!-- <start-class>com.infosys.roster.SpringBootRosterAppApplication</start-class> -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--encryption lib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-springsecurity3</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>

        </dependency>


<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> -->
<!--         <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> -->
<!--         <version>5.2.10.Final</version> -->
<!--   </dependency> -->

        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>io.springfox</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>2.7.0</version> -->
        <!-- <scope>compile</scope> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->


        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>io.springfox</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>2.7.0</version> -->
        <!-- <scope>compile</scope> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->

        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>io.springfox</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>2.7.0</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
server.port=
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.datasource.url=


spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Should remove unknown error in pom.xml and also I must be able to populate values in H2 db.

Comment: Are you saying no one else is having an issue with the same pom file?

Comment: update the error log in question

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes none of them in my team is facing the issue with the code base I'm using. Only I am facing this issue

Comment: @vels4j I am not getting any error log when I run the application, but in pom.xml it is showing as "unknown error"

Comment: I didn’t mean the code base but the actual pom file

Comment: Are you using intelliJ? This is a longshot, but I suggest to do maven->clean, then do maven->install. Sometimes IntelliJ keeps old/partial builds lingering around. Despite the fact that maven->install also does a clean, it is important to do a separate clean.

Comment: @user1884155 I am using Eclipse Oxygen version. I have also done maven clean and then maven install, but nothing seems to work

Comment: if your maven commands are working i would recommend to remove the files generated by Eclipse. Not sure which files as I do not use Eclipse but you can find googling.

Comment: *....getting Unknown error in line1 of pom.xml*...where is line 1??

Comment: @CommonMan Accidentally Line 1 was commented out when I pasted in stackoverflow. But thats not the problem. I am still getting the same error

Comment: @Carlos I tried deleting .m2 files generated by eclipse. I even uninstalled eclipse and installed spring tool suite. But no luck

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I've created several new spring boot projects from http://start.spring.io, and after importing the projects into Spring Tool Suite, I'm getting 'Unknown Error' on line 1 of my pom.xml file. This just started this week.

Comment: I've tried the following:
- tried renaming my .m2 folder and letting maven re-download all of the dependencies
- I've deleted and recreated the entire pom.xml file
- I created a new project on http://start.spring.io that's a higher version.

None of this has worked for me. I'm still getting the 'Unknown Error' on the first line of the pom.xml file.

Comment: @Stephen Are you still facing this issue. I was able to solve after changing         <version>2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version> to <version>2.1.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

Comment: @Shravani, that fixed it for me. Thank you for following up with me!

Comment: *Refer the below Solution* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157105/project-is-running-and-working-but-pom-xml-is-showing-error/60213827#60213827

Answer (score 186, accepted):

**answer according to current status**

[This issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547340#c9) got fixed:

> Please install the m2e connector for mavenarchiver plugin 0.17.3 from https://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/1.4/

---

**obsolete answer**

A less profound change than a downgrade from Spring Boot `2.1.5.RELEASE` to `2.1.4.RELEASE` would be downgrading only [the affected Maven JAR Plugin](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547340) from `3.1.2` to `3.1.1` as long as this bug exists:

```
<properties>
    <!-- ... -->
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: The newest Eclipse (2019-03) has the same problem. Changing the maven-jar-plugin from 3.1.2 to 3.1.1 based on your suggestion solved the issue. Many thanks.

Comment: obsolete answer was the solution that worked for me

Comment: Just for the record, my problem was solved by upgrading the mavenarchiver plugin.

Comment: after installing m2e connector for mavenarchiver plugin, restart maven & do maven -->update project-->force update of snapshots

Comment: installing the latest m2e connector for mavenarchiver fixed it for me

Comment: Yes. Inside properties you must have <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>. Then you right click on the project in the project explorer and choose "Maven -> Update Project..."

Comment: Some times behind a corporate proxy the m2e connector plugin download in eclipse may take more time to load and consumes huge memory, in such cases, below answer helps
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59300898/3625752

Answer (score 51):

Add 3.1.1 in to properties like below than fix issue

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

Just Update Project => right click => Maven=> Update Project

Comment: This issue seems to appear from maven-jar-plugin 3.1.2 & 3.2.0.

Comment: yes but 3.1.1 is working fine so we can use that one

Comment: 3.2.2 Still showing the error. 3.1.1 is the latest that works for me without the error.

Answer (score 36):

For me I changed  in the parent tag of the pom.xml and it solved it
change 2.1.5 to 2.1.4 then Maven-> Update Project

Comment: same here! still not sure what in the spring parent pom causes this problem since 2.1.5

Comment: @fsuwailih Thanks this one worked. But I am wondering why is it only working for some people but not for others.

Comment: This solution actually worked! I changed it to 2.1.4 from 2.1.6. But why the later versions are causing that error?

Answer (score 23):

As per the suggestion from @Shravani, in my pom.xml file, I changed my version number in the  area from this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

to this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I then right clicked on the project and did a 'Maven -> Update project...'. This made the problem go away for me.

Comment: The only correct answer.

Answer (score 15):

You must **to upgrade the m2e connector**.
It's a known bug, but there is a solution:

1. Into Eclipse click "Help" > "Install new Software..."
2. Appears a window. In the "Install" window:

   2a. Into the input box "Work with", enter next site location and press Enter
   https://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/1.4/

   2b. Appears a lot of information into "Name" input Box. Select all the items

   2c. Click "Next" Button.

Finish the installation and restart Eclipse.

Comment: I found these instructions the clearest path to implementing the solution that everyone says is the root cause problem, the need to upgrade this connector.  _Also, it worked._ :^)

Answer (score 13):

[There is a bug about Eclipse and spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.5](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547340)

"if the maven packaging attribute is war then no problem.The problem is in jar type." So you can also fix this problem by changing packaging type.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Comment: this did it for me

Answer (score 4):

I updated spring tool suits by going `help` > `check for update`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add below maven jar version in properties tag in pom.xml,
<maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>

Then follow below steps,

Step 1: mvn clean

Step 2 : update project

Problem solved for me! You should also try this :)

Comment: Really Helpful ! 
I added that below the  java version      <java.version>1.8</java.version> 
 and updated the project and did refresh on STS, It worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot reproduce your error (as none of your team mates can either), I have a suggestion, that might help you.

Have you heard of the [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)? As it appears on line 1 it is a likely candidate for your troubles. Maybe you changed a setting somewhere that somehow leads to the error. This quote from the Wikipedia article is particularly relevant I think:

> BOM use is optional. Its presence interferes with the use of UTF-8 by software that does not expect non-ASCII bytes at the start of a file but that could otherwise handle the text stream.

Comment: After changing the version for parent tag it worked magically

Answer (score 1):

For me I changed in the parent tag of the **pom.xml** and it solved it `change 2.1.5 to 2.1.4` then `Maven-> Update Project`. its worked for me also.

Answer (score 1):

same problem for me, original code from spring starter demo gives unknown error on line 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...
```

Changing just the version of 2.1.6.RELEASE to 2.1.4.RELEASE fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me, changing pom.xml for SpringBoot 2 project from 2.1.6.RELEASE

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.REL`enter code here`EASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

to 2.1.4.RELEASE verified and works

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: I meant 2.1.4.RELEASE.

Comment: Edited my answer and fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error on eclipse IDE version 4.10, Spring boot 2.2.0.M4, changed the Spring boot version to 2.2.0.M2 (after many other solutions recommended and it solved the error). Maybe something missing or broken in the latest version of Spring boot starter project module maven POM.

Answer (score 0):

> In my pom.xml file I had to downgrade the version from 2.1.6.RELEASE for
>   spring-boot-starter-parent artifact to 2.1.4.RELEASE

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

to be changed to

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

And that weird **Unknown error** disappeared

Answer (score 0):

You just need a latest Eclipse or Spring tool suite 4.5 and above.Nothing else.refresh project and it works

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error in Version 3. It worked after **upgrading STS to latest version: 4.5.1.RELEASE**. No change in code or configuration in latest STS was required.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you facing this type of error simply change the
Release version  just like
In my case  it is showing Error in 2.2.7 I changed to 2.2.6

Problem:

```xml
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
```

Solution:

```xml
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version> in property tag

problem resolve

https://medium.com/@saannjaay/unknown-error-in-pom-xml-66fb2414991b

Answer (score 0):

My silly solution was to just "Delete" the error message in the problems list.

Right click => select delete and you get a warning message saying it may come back.
But the error message has not returned even after I did a clean
and Build All.

**TLDR**:

I did the following from the command line
**"mvn clean"**   Result : No errors

**"mvn compile"** Result: Jar build in target folder.
Result : No errors on screen.

So the error is in eclipse not in the pom.xml

I tried the following:

Update Project => right click => Maven=> Update Project

Project => clean
Autobuild results in the same error message.

I tried changing the packaging from a jar to a war in the pom.xml
Rebuild... Still the same error message.

I tried the "upgrade the m2e connector" option.
Rebuild... Still the same error message.

I tried turn off automatic rebuild, clean and exit Eclipse.
Restart Eclipse and Build all... Still the same error message.

Maybe one of the above fixed it for me it just did not update or clear the problem logs in Eclipse properly.

Answer (score 0):

If someone having similar issues in VS Code please follow this:
Open pom.xml >> Right Click and select "Update Project"

Answer (score -1):

Following actions worked for me.

1.Go to Project in toolbar -> Unchecked "Build Automatically"

2.In POM File,Downgrade the spring-boot version to 2.1.4 RELEASE.

3.Right Click on Project name -> Select Maven -> Click on "Update Project". ->OK
Wait till all the maven dependency to get downloaded(Need internet).