# Pom.xml file has a red X over it in Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

my projects pom.xml has a red X over it and when I go into the "Problems" tab, Eclipse is showing an Error message.

Problems tab gives the following message:

Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.lazerycode.selenium:driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin:1.0.18:selenium (execution: default, phase: test-compile)

How to remove this red X over pom.xml?
Java version is 1.8

[Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avnsP.png)

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>selenium-tests</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.lazerycode.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <rootStandaloneServerDirectory>${project.basedir}/ServerExes/selenium_standalone_binaries</rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                        <downloadedZipFileDirectory>${project.basedir}/ServerExes/selenium_standalone_zips</downloadedZipFileDirectory>
                        <customRepositoryMap>${project.basedir}/TestData/RepositoryMap.xml</customRepositoryMap>
                        <overwriteFilesThatExist>${overwrite.binaries}</overwriteFilesThatExist>
                        <onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem>true</onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem>
                        <fileDownloadRetryAttempts>${retry.attempts}</fileDownloadRetryAttempts>
                        <fileDownloadReadTimeout>${read.timeout}</fileDownloadReadTimeout>
                        <operatingSystems>
                            <windows>true</windows>
                            <linux>true</linux>
                            <mac>true</mac>
                        </operatingSystems>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>selenium</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
                            <!-- <file>testNg_UI_Verification.xml</file> -->
                            <!-- <file></file> -->
                            <file>${testNGFileName}</file>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>suitethreadpoolsize</name>
                                <value>2</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <proxyEnabled>${proxyEnabled}</proxyEnabled>
                            <proxyHost>${proxyHost}</proxyHost>
                            <proxyPort>${proxyPort}</proxyPort>
                            <phantomjs.binary.path>${phantomjs.binary.path}</phantomjs.binary.path>
                            <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome.driver}</webdriver.chrome.driver>
                            <webdriver.ie.driver>${webdriver.ie.driver}</webdriver.ie.driver>
                            <webdriver.opera.driver>${webdriver.opera.driver}</webdriver.opera.driver>
                            <webdriver.gecko.driver>${webdriver.gecko.driver}</webdriver.gecko.driver>
                            <webdriver.edge.driver>${webdriver.edge.driver}</webdriver.edge.driver>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        
                        <additionalClasspathElements>
                           <additionalClasspathElement>${project.basedir}/db_queries/ojdbc14.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                        </additionalClasspathElements>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56142369/why-am-i-getting-unknown-error-in-line-1-of-pom-xml
same problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting Unknown error in line 1 of pom.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56142369/why-am-i-getting-unknown-error-in-line-1-of-pom-xml)

Comment: Non of the suggested solutions is working. Tried the m2e-wtp install, didn't help. Tried to add the <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version> and yet again, it didn't help. The rest of solutions there are related to spring-boot and that doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 0):

If despite the error you can execute the project then you can use "Mark goal selenium as ignored in eclipse preferences".

Comment: This does remove the error, so thumbs up. But doesn't answer why the error was there in the first place.